# Where does the fate map of a human embryo end?

Tags: human-biology

I'm confused about the fate map of a human embryo. Is it just a particular part of the embryo development or does it include everything, from the conception (germinal stage) to the day the baby is born?

Comment: Are you talking about projects like this: [http://embryo.asu.edu/pages/fate-map](http://embryo.asu.edu/pages/fate-map)?

Comment: @Chris Yes, but it doesn't give any information about the fate map of a human

Comment: Ok, I will answer this later today.

Answer (score 2):

In the developing embryo you have the three germ layers: Endoderm, mesoderm and ectoderm. From these layers all cell lineages of the body develop and can be traced back through their differentiation and migration to this three layers.
Have a look on the image below, which illustrates this pretty nicely:

[image]

The figure is part of [this](http://pqdtopen.proquest.com/pqdtopen/doc/305016519.html?FMT=ABS) PhD thesis, which also seems worth reading when you are interested in this topic.

Comment: Great figure!  The thesis (p20) cites the image as "adapted from Gilberts Developmental Biology, Fourth edition, Figure 9.1."

Comment: That is right. I don't have access to the Gilbert, so this should be ok.